# Mysql Count Columns Greater Than 0

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, average

I have a database such as:

```
USER   12am 1am 2am 3am 4am 5am 6am 7am 8am 9am 10am 11am 12pm
--------------------------------------------------------------
user1   5    0   6   7   8   0   9   0   0   0   0    0    0
```

I want the average of all the columns. 
I can easily add up the columns, but I would like to get a count of the columns where the value is greater than 0. 
In this case it would be 5. 
That way I could divide 35/5 and get 7.

Comment: oh, please normalize your table, this design is awful.  This would be significantly easier with a normalized table.

Comment: stackoverflow should create "sql denormalized" badges... lots off question about this..

Comment: @RaymondNijland call it "Abnormal Insight" or maybe, "Paranormal Experiences"

Comment: The same way as you sum values in columns, but add `IF(val1>0,1,0)+(val2>0,1,0) +...`... No need mentioning normalization I guess.

Comment: @bluefeet however ... you can wield the UNPIVOT of Justice and Restoration

Comment: Thank you a1ex07 for answering my question. I understand normalization but it in no way helps me accomplish what I need to do. Your suggestion straightened me out. Can you post this as the answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: @user1621308 i'm curious how it helped? also ... i'm not sure i've ever seen IF-THEN in a DML statement. You could use CASE ... so SUM(CASE WHEN val1 > 0 THEN val1 ELSE 0 END + ... CASE WHEN val2 > 0 THEN val2 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: @user1621308 what are you trying to accomplish? open hours for users?

Comment: @swasheck: `IF` is a (MySQL) function, not a statement, in this case.

Comment: @AndriyM well thank you ... dont think i knew that. i guess that's yet another fascinating curiosity with mysql

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.user, 
        (
             (a.12am + a.1am + a.2am + a.3am + a.4am + a.5am + a.6am + a.7am + a.8am + a.9am + a.10am + a.11am + a.12pm) 
            / 
             (IF(a.12am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.1am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.2am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.3am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.4am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.5am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.6am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.7am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.8am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.9am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.10am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.11am > 0, 1, 0) + 
              IF(a.12pm > 0, 1, 0)
             )
        )
FROM tableA a 
GROUP BY a.user;
```